# NET6 - Intellisense is not showing my table/DBSet under DBContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

After configuring DBContext, the DBSet that I added ("MyTable") is not showing up in Intellisense. I have EFCore Design, SQLServer and Tools installed, all v6.0.11.
Please look at my code in the screenshots below and let me know what I am missing.
Note: I haven't run the project yet since doing all of the below DBContext configuration.

[My DBContext Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTTRr.png)

[MyTable just has some string properties, that's it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaFIC.png)

[Doing configuration in Program.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVtQf.png)

[MyTable dbset not showing up in Intellisense.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyo68.png)

Comment: Because you declared _dbContext as `DbContext` isntead of `MyDbContext`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot see your `MyTable` property because you are using base class `DbContext` and not your own implementation which is `MyContext` class.

[image]

In 11 line, you should change

```
private readonly DbContext _dbContext
```

For

```
private readonly MyContext _dbContext
```